# ffmpeg scroll overlay. How to end scroll with image remaining till end of input

Tags: ffmpeg

The code below scrolls an image from the bottom of the output frame and, using the enable option, stops at the 9sec position. However, the last frame of the scrolled image does not remain till the end of the output. My workaround is to create a second overlay of the image at the point the scroll ends. Is there a more elegant way I can achieve this?

```
    ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i image.png -filter_complex [0][1]overlay=x=0:y=H-2*n:enable='between(t,0,9)'[OUT] -map [OUT] out.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
overlay=x=0:y='H-2*clip(t,0,9)'
```

`clip` function limits the value to be between 2nd and 3rd arguments.

[update] here is a way to scroll the frame from bottom to top in 9 seconds:

```
overlay=x=0:y='H*(1-clip(t,0,9)/9)'
```

If you are stopping somewhere midway, then do

```
overlay=x=0:y='H-clip(2*n,0,450)'
```

Comment: Firstly apologies, Have edited my code. Should have read 2*n  not 2*t. Clip function no longer scrolls image.

Comment: Probably your effect is too fast and moves too little. (transition ends in 9 frames, which could be <0.3 seconds at 30 fps and it only shows the first 18 rows of the image at the end.) Work out the math and tweak it.

Comment: The 9 represents seconds, not frames. 2*n represents 2 pixels per frame. At my 25fps the image moves 50 pixels per second for 9 seconds. This is exactly what happens when you run the script. However, at the end of the 9 seconds the image stops and disappears. I appreciate this is how the enable function is intended to work. I was hoping for a simple adjustment, or alternative, that leaves the last frame visible until the end of the output.

Comment: If you know the frame rate, all you need to do is to use the `t = n/25` relationship to adjust the equation. A couple other approaches (without mixing up `n` and `t`) have been added to the response

Answer (score 1):

@kesh That's exactly what I was looking for.

Following allows start and end time adjustment. End image remains till end of output.

```
    ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 1.png -filter_complex ^
    "[0][1]overlay=x=0:y='H+(START)-clip(2*n,0,END)'" out.mp4
```

START = 2 x Input frame Rate x Start time in seconds.

END   = 2 X Input frame Rate x End time in seconds.